# updating a variable in appDelegate

Tags: objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate

In the application delegate, I created an array for multiple view controllers to reference. However, when I try to update the array in one view, it comes up empty in the other.

View 1:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
dataTempForSearch = appDelegate.myData;
```

I then have an xml parser that inserts an object into the array.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CompanyName"]) {
        // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
        [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:currentAddress forKey:@"address"];
        [item setObject:currentCity forKey:@"city"];
        [item setObject:currentCountry forKey:@"country"];

        [dataTempForSearch addObject:[item copy]];
    }
}
```

This returns everything fine in view 1, but in view 2 I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    dataTempForMap = appDelegate.myData;

    NSLog(@"myData appDelegate from: %@", dataTempForMap);      
}
```

when this second view is loaded, the `dataTempForMap` returns an empty array.

Comment: I think you probably need to show where myData is initialized and anywhere the property is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you are reinitializing the array over the original populated one.  I'd put a breakpoint on the spot where you're doing

```
myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and see if it's being called more often then you thought.

Comment: You're right...I was doing this elsewhere further down in my code...I'm an eediot haha

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have not initialized the myData array in the delegate. You should be calling

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

in your

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
```

method. Otherwise the pointer you are getting back from the delegate is not pointing to an instance of NSMutableArray

I would then check with the debugger that you are not getting nil back and that you are getting the same address back. If either of these are not true I suspect that order in which things is happening is the problem

Comment: I actually am doing just that. For the record too, it is an NSMutableArray.